# Formatting Urls made easier?

Tags: java, html, string, jsoup

I was just wondering is there a more generic method of doing this. I scrape a webpage and get all the links on it, problem being a lot of them are relative

```
e.g /index.html e.g /home.index.html
```

So far I have being trying to account for this by adding the home URL. `e.g .index.html` becomes `www.example.com/index.html` etc. (I need to do this because I want to connect to each link using HttpCLient)

My problem is there is so much to account for when doing this. Is there a more simpler way of doing this that i'm missing.

Thanks in advance :)

```
 ps I can get all the links just wondering if jsoup or httpclient
 has a better way of formatting the URLs.
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The JSoup doc says for your use case:

> **Problem**  You have a HTML document that contains  relative URLs, which you need to resolve to absolute URLs.
>
> **Solution**
>
> Make sure you specify a base URI when parsing the document (which is
>   implicit when loading from a URL), and Use the abs: attribute prefix
>   to resolve an absolute URL from an attribute:
>
> ```
> Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://jsoup.org").get();
>
> Element link = doc.select("a").first();
> String relHref = link.attr("href"); // == "/"
> String absHref = link.attr("abs:href"); // "http://jsoup.org/"
> ```

Source: [JSoup Doc](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how does that change a link "index.html" to "www.example.com/index.html"?

Comment: From what I read, if you specifiy the root URL, then all links which are relative in your document will automatically prefixed with the domain, when you query with "abs:href".